# How do I transfer wares for a mission?

Tags: x4-foundations

How do I transfer wares to finish a mission?

[image: Transfer Wares through the Ship Menu: Antimatter Cells]

I'm docked at the correct ship, but transfer wares is disabled in the menu.

[image: Can't transfer docked on Oberth]

I'm at the correct ship:

[image: Mission is to Oberth]

And I have the antimatter cells in my inventory:

[image: 10 Antimatter Cells]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selling the antimatter cells in trade worked to complete the mission.